# Need an Excel VBA macro to divide a cell into multiple cells depending on a specific character

Tags: excel, vba

I have a mailing list full of names and addresses for university prospectuses, taken from a .tab file, in an excel document. But the addresses are contained within a single cell, with each line seperated by a carriage return.

I really need a macro I can run which will seperate the different parts into different cells. I basically know the structure, but have no idea about VBA's capabilities.

It needs to scan until a carriage return appears, put the preceding data, minus the carriage return into a new cell, then continue on until there are no characters left in the cell, as there is no carriage return at the end.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's code for your VBA macro:

```
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range

Set rngSource = Sheet1.Range("A1:A5") ' or wherever your list is
Set rngDestination = Sheet1.Range("C1") ' parsed data will be placed here

rngSource.TextToColumns _
    Destination:=rngDestination , _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    Other:=True, _
    OtherChar:=vbLf ' This is where you define your delimiter character
```

where `vbLf` is the same as `Chr(10)`, assuming that's your delimiter. Depending on your flavour of carriage return, you may need to use `vbCr` (or, equivalently, `Chr(13)`) instead.

Note that @Jon Egerton's non-macro way of doing it works just fine. However, if it needs to be done more than once, I tend to grow weary of all the clicking, selecting, typing, copying, special pasting, pasting in the wrong place and having to start over, etc. I find VBA macros are much more reusable. It's a matter of taste, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without VBA as follows:

(I'm assuming your data is in column A)

1. Use this formula in Column B to replace the carriage returns: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR("10"),"|")`
2. Copy Column B and use PasteSpecial - Values to copy the actual Data into Column C
3. Use Text-To-Columns on Column C to split the text by | into separate cells from D onwards

Hope this helps

Comment: @Jean: I always forget its not REPLACE.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It works perfectly, but I'm from a programming background, so prefer the ease of just running the macro. But I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You can always just record these actions into a macro, to get you started with the code then.